# Download Multiple Images with ahref as Zip in jquery

Tags: jquery, dicom, dcm4che

Iam working with dicom images using dcm4che.
Iam setting wado request to ahref in order to download the images but iam not getting it.
This is my html code with wado request:

```
 <a class="myFile" href="http://xxxxx/wado?requestType=WADO&amp;studyUID=1.2.840.113704.1.111.6028.1515205296.94&amp;seriesUID=1.2.840.113704.1.111.3616.1515205367.2&amp;objectUID=1.2.840.113704.1.111.8164.1515205401.69892" download="download.jpeg"></a>
 <a class="myFile" href="http://xxxxx/wado?requestType=WADO&amp;studyUID=1.2.840.113704.1.111.6028.1515205296.94&amp;seriesUID=1.2.840.113704.1.111.3616.1515205367.2&amp;objectUID=1.2.840.113704.7.1.1.8556.1515205401.2"></a>
 <a class="myFile" href="http://xxxxx/wado?requestType=WADO&amp;studyUID=1.2.840.113704.1.111.6028.1515205296.94&amp;seriesUID=1.2.840.113704.1.111.3616.1515205367.2&amp;objectUID=1.2.840.113704.7.1.1.912.1515205428.1"></a>
```

This is my Jquery Code:

```
var a=document.getElementsByClassName('myFile');
a.setAttribute('download', 'download.jpeg');
a.click();
```

I need to download all ahref link as in zip... 
Can anyone solve my problem???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try With this:

```
var i;
for(i=0;i<$('.myFile').length;i++){
   var a=document.getElementByClassName('.myFile')[e];
   a.setAttribute('download','download.jpeg');
   a.click();
 }
```